# Struts 1: how do i get session variable in DAO layer

Tags: java, struts-1, struts1

I am using struts 1 (maintenance tasks on a legacy project). The application is tiered in ActionClasses calling Manager classes and Manager classes instantiating and using DAO layer classes/

I have to code conditional logic, where based on a session variable, I want DAO layer to switch between different DB2 schemas.

How do I read session in a DAO java class?
One obvious way is to refactor manager/dao class constructors to pass along session variables all through call-chain

in struts 2, we use `ActionContext.getContext().getSession();`

is there something like that which I can do in struts 1 ?

---EDIT For all the purists (including me)-------------

I am working on this code-base, for prototyping updated business logic. This is a code that's inherited , wrote way back in 2003-2004. After prototyping, this code will not be used at-all, going straight to recycle-bin.

I understand that DAO doesn't need to access HTTP session, and that's what I follow when i write my code.

But my question is, is there a way to access session in DAO in struts 1 framework (filters/hacks?)

Comment: Why do not you just pass a variable with the value that you need?

Comment: DAO layer shouldn't do access to context information such HTTP session, as Paul commented it should be a good alternative to pass this value as parameter to your dao method

Comment: I am passing the variable now, but there are 100+ classes that need the refactoring. That is why I posted the question, if there is a way to get session in DAO, that way I can limit changes to DAO, instead of refactoring all classes in the chain.

Comment: How would such a design ever be considered "layered"?  If you aren't going to keep boundaries between layers, why not just dump everything into one monster servlet and get it over with?  A good refactoring IDE will make short work of it.  Do you really have 100+ classes in your persistence tier, all relying on session?  Wait - you said Struts 1.  Now I understand.

Comment: Working on inherited code, last touched in 2004, with a tight deadline. I understand the concept of better layered architecture, but in real world, its not common to come across inherited code, where fixes are needed.

Comment: This is not a real world situation, if you give in by providing a whack solution to the already bad situation, then in 2017, the next person who comes in would say "guy in 2012 already gave access to session in DAO, its a real world situation". :) Need some integrity into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to have a thread local, maybe set in a filter or trivially-customized request processor, accessed via a static method. I feel dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this.  You'll be setting yourself for massive headaches in the future.  Instead, pass the value through the call chain.

Comment: edited question above, after my prototyping, there is no future, the code's going straight to recycle bin. There is a better "Spring" based version already in development.

Comment: Okay.  I've heard this so many times, I always do it the right way anyway.  Saves me heartache.  ymmv

Comment: +1 "Okay. I've heard this so many times, I always do it the right way anyway"

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, try ThreadLocal only to learn that the request can spawn child threads, you can use a combination of ServletRequestListener (Java EE) and RequestContextHolder (Spring-web) to achieve this:

```
    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        ServletRequest sr = sre.getServletRequest();
        if(sr instanceof HttpServletRequest)
            // second parameter will let child threads inherit this object
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes((HttpServletRequest) sr), true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        ServletRequest sr = sre.getServletRequest();
        if(sr instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
        }
    }
```

And then in any place you need the HttpSession:

```
            ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
            HttpSession httpSession = attr.getRequest().getSession(false); // true == allow create
```